# How can i loop through all the <td> tags in a row and get the values on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through all the  elements in a tow on a button click

my button:

```
`<a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>`
```

my onclick method:

```
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function() {
        var textval = $(this).text(); 
        console.log('textval');
   });
```

For some reason this isn't printing our anything at all, its not even going into the code in the each.

I tried printing `console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td').text())`

but it just shows empty text.

Here is my table rows:

```
            <table id="productsTable" class="table-saas table table-hover" data-pagination="true" data-page-size="10">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 15%; " data-field="name">
            <div class="th-inner ">Name</div>
            <div class="fht-cell"></div>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 15%; " data-field="store_url">
            <div class="th-inner ">Store URL</div>
            <div class="fht-cell"></div>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 15%; " data-field="status">
            <div class="th-inner ">Status</div>
            <div class="fht-cell"></div>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 15%; " data-field="created_at">
            <div class="th-inner ">Created At</div>
            <div class="fht-cell"></div>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 25%; " data-field="notes">
            <div class="th-inner ">Notes</div>
            <div class="fht-cell"></div>
        </th>
        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; " data-field="operate">
            <div class="th-inner "></div>
            <div class="fht-cell"></div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-index="0">
        <td style="width: 15%; ">test 1221321</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">-</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">pending review</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">about 3 hours</td>
        <td style="width: 25%; ">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; "><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="approveProduct()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a><a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct()" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="1">
        <td style="width: 15%; ">prepend this product</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">-</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">pending review</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">about 3 hours</td>
        <td style="width: 25%; ">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; "><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="approveProduct()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a><a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct()" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="2">
        <td style="width: 15%; ">test product 2</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">-</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">pending review</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">about 3 hours</td>
        <td style="width: 25%; ">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; "><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="approveProduct()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a><a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct()" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="3">
        <td style="width: 15%; ">Test product append</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">-</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">pending review</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">about 3 hours</td>
        <td style="width: 25%; ">-</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; "><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="approveProduct()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a><a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct()" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="4">
        <td style="width: 15%; ">Pet Grooming Deshedding Brush Glove&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">-</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">pending review</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">about 2 months</td>
        <td style="width: 25%; ">This is a test note to see wtf the table does with it</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; "><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="approveProduct()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a><a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct()" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="5">
        <td style="width: 15%; ">LED Dog Collar</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">-</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">pending review</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">about 2 months</td>
        <td style="width: 25%; ">This is a test note to see wtf the table does with it</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; "><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="approveProduct()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a><a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct()" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="6">
        <td style="width: 15%; ">Pet Grooming Deshedding Brush Glove&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">-</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">pending review</td>
        <td style="width: 15%; ">about 2 months</td>
        <td style="width: 25%; ">This is a test note to see wtf the table does with it</td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; "><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="approveProduct()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a><a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct()" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

loading my data via an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/product/fetch_admin_products",
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    success: function(resp) {

        if (resp) {
            if (resp.products) {

                setupTable(resp.products)
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(resp) {


    },
});

$('#productsTable').bootstrapTable({
 data: data,
 columns: [ 
    { width: "15%" },
    { width: "15%" },
    { width: "15%" },
    { width: "15%" },
    { width: "25%" },
    {
      field: 'operate',
      title: '',
      width: '15%',
      align: 'center',
      valign: 'middle',
      clickToSelect: false,
      formatter : function(value,row,index) {
        //return '<input name="elementname"  value="'+value+'"/>';
        return  '<a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="approveProduct()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>' +
                '<a href="#" onclick="deleteProduct()" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'
      }
    }
  ],       
});
```

Any clue on what i'm doing wrong?
Should i be taking a diffrent approach to this?

Comment: It looks like you don't have any `td`s, so `.find('td')` won't find anything

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry i forgot to add that i am loading json data

Comment: No matter what you're loading from, if the table doesn't have `td`, you won't be able to `.find` any `td`s

Comment: @CertainPerformance but when i inspect the page i can see the td elements. Shouldn't it be able to find it?

Comment: @RickS have you tried the same thing but with vanillajs?

Comment: If the elements exist on the page, then post that HTML instead, not the code without any `td`s. (don't post pictures of code, post the actual HTML code)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay i updated it to show the actual table code on the page

Comment: You probably don't use `closest` correctly. You do not mention where your button (`anchor`) is actually located within the DOM-tree, but since it is not in the table (your code doesn't show it), I assume it's outside the table, so `closest` cannot find anything. Here is a `jsFiddle` using your code snippets and the `id` instead of `closest`: https://jsfiddle.net/u6t8s1mu/2/

Comment: @Philipp The last <td> tag in each row is 3 buttons, im using those buttons to call my onclick method

Comment: Sorry didn't see the column. The reason is, when you call `viewProduct()` on `onclick`, your `this` within `viewProduct` is `window` and not the clicked `a`. Use `onclick="viewProduct(this)"` when you call it and change `viewProduct` to accept a parameter `function viewProduct(el)` and change `$(this)` to `$(el)`, see https://jsfiddle.net/u6t8s1mu/3/ ... another solution would be to use `call` or `apply` with `this` as first parameter: `viewProduct.call(this)`

Comment: @Philipp you're a life saver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in your code, the calling context of `viewProduct` is `window`, not the `td`, resulting in `$(this).closest('tr')` failing:

```js
function viewProduct () {
  console.log(this.location.href);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-index="0">
      <td style="width: 15%; ">test 1221321</td>
      <td style="width: 15%; ">-</td>
      <td style="width: 15%; ">pending review</td>
      <td style="width: 15%; ">about 3 hours</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; ">-</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; "><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="approveProduct()" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" onclick="viewProduct()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye">view</i></a>
        <a
          href="#" onclick="deleteProduct()" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead, attach the event handler properly with Javascript, and you can reference the desired `td` and its containing `tr` explicitly. For example:

```js
const td = document.querySelector('td:last-child');
td.onclick = function() {
  [...td.parentElement.children].forEach(td => console.log(td.textContent));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-index="0">
      <td style="width: 15%; ">test 1221321</td>
      <td style="width: 15%; ">-</td>
      <td style="width: 15%; ">pending review</td>
      <td style="width: 15%; ">about 3 hours</td>
      <td style="width: 25%; ">-</td>
      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 15%; "><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a><a href="#" style="margin-right: 5px" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-eye">view</i></a>
        <a
          href="#" class="btn  btn-danger btn-xs"><i style="font-size: 15px" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```